# Is spork worth the hassle?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spork

I have spent hours and hours trying to configure spork so that it works for RSpec, works for Cucumber, reloads models so that it doesn't have to be restarted all the time and doesn't throw errors.

I've spent so much time researching solutions to its quirks that I might as well just have waited for the regular tests to load. Added to all of that it has the annoying characteristic that when I'm debugging I type commands into the terminal window I called Rspec from but the output gets displayed in the terminal window Spork is running in. Eesh.

I'm hugely appreciative of any piece of software that is produced for the help of others and of the spork project but just can't figure out whether it's worth labouring through further.

**EDIT**

YES - SPORK IS DEFINITELY WORTH THE EFFORT. After 4 days of setup I finally managed to sort out all of the issues and it's speeded up my testing incredibly. I really thoroughly recommend it.

Comment: I was wondering too, but I'd say that once you've done it, you have a much quicker workflow and that's really great.

Comment: I'm agree but I'm just not convinced it's every going to be done.

Comment: I think it's worth it. How about being more picky about when you update your gems? If you don't update your gems then things will keep working as-is right?

Comment: It's not a problem with gems - it's simply that there are a succession of issues that crop up with it including getting the whole reloading classes thing to work, debugging and now it isn't dealing with inherited controller classes. I've just run out of patience

Answer (score 4):

I found out that Spork seems to work mostly OK if you follow the TDD/BDD pattern - that is, you write your test first, let it fail, and only then write the code. However, I don't always work this way - there are many situations where I need to write the code before writing the tests.

Fortunately, I found a nearly ideal solution to my testing needs - the [Spin gem](https://github.com/jstorimer/spin). It doesn't force you into into any workflow, and just works.

Comment: spin looks nice and much easier to set up than spork, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Give my [CoreApp](https://github.com/bsodmike/CoreApp) ago - it's a complete config of RSpec/Spork/Guard/Cucumber.

I find it's worthwhile considering it speeds up mosts test but the disadvantage then is my tests aren't engineered to be 'efficient' themselves.  Some believe it's better to wait for the environment to load each time, but on my MBP it takes over 10-15 secs for the env to reload.

https://github.com/bsodmike/CoreApp

Comment: Do accept my answer if it satisfies you... I'm TDDing almost daily with this setup.  Even figured out how to 'disable' Cucumber just by commenting a few spots in CoreApp.

Comment: @Maichael de Silva - I will definitely come back and mark it if it works. I've had to put Spork to one side for the moment but it'll come up again, ty

Comment: My pleasure! You can also try some of the [app templates (generators) here](http://railswizard.org/).